# Am using Kubuntu 20.04 and no KDE Plasma 5.18 no update to 5.24

Tags: updates, kubuntu, plasma, kde5

I sent a bug report and was told that I needed to update from KDE Plasma version 5.18 to 5.24 as the bug had been fixed. I update everyday almost, whenever updates are available. Tried to find a way to update just KDE Plasma, but found none. Is there a terminal command to do this? Obviously just update is not doing it for me.

Comment: I found this https://www.debugpoint.com/2021/10/upgrade-kde-plasma-5-23/ but it states that you have to enable the `kubuntu/beta` repository to upgrade to the newer or newest version.  It is also a kind of at your own risk, or you can try to file a feature request to have Canonical add it to the official repos, or it looks like you might be able to wait 22.04 LTS release next month.  They will also push the official release upgrade when the first point release comes out in July.

Comment: Thanks. I don't really want to do anything "at your own risk" but I guess I don't understand why it wasn't updated along with the rest of Kubuntu; I mean, it's Ubuntu with KDE so why no updates on the KDE Plasma?  Filing a feature request could take longer than the next LTS release so I guess I wait and put up with the bugs till then.

Comment: 22.04 is going to be available on 21.04.2022. You can directly upgrade to that then, or do it now [if you are ready](https://computingforgeeks.com/upgrade-from-ubuntu-focal-fossa-to-ubuntu-jammy-jellyfish/). Disable all PPAs if you do it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS uses the LTS version of Qt5 (5.12).  You have received all upgrades that are possible with that LTS version of Qt (*which was 5.12.3 if I recall at release; and now sits at 5.12.8*).

For users who want stability; they can remain on the LTS release, using LTS libraries & toolkits - at cost of using older software.

To upgrade to later Qt5 & KF5 (KDE Frameworks) as required by newer KDE Plasma versions, Kubuntu offers that via upgrading your entire stack using non-LTS releases, ie.

- Kubuntu 20.10
- Kubuntu 21.04
- Kubuntu 21.10

These later releases have newer KDE Plasma, and the required later (non-LTS) toolkits/libraries of Qt5 & KF5.

Comment: Thanks, that clears things up. Guess I figured if the bug is reported to KDE and they say you should upgrade, it meant it was possible. Preferring LTS is why I have not upgraded from 20.04 .

Comment: Your *off-topic* alternative is always KDE Neon..  It uses the base *focal* system, but incorporates packages from *groovy* (20.10), then *hirsute* (21.04), and now *impish* (21.10) to allow later KF5/Qt5 allowing later KDE Plasma.. but it's not a 20.04 system, but mixture of multiple releases; off-topic here.. and cannot be *release-upgraded* like a Ubuntu system as easily (*due to mix of packages within*).  KDE Neon does share some support sites with Kubuntu - but it's off-topic here (*and off-topic on like Ubuntu sites*).